# Making XamlReader working with VS 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I spent many hours trying to get `XamlReader` work with VS 2015. All examples I've come across (including MSDN's) produce compilation errors(!).

Here are my best attempts (`MyXAMLFile.xaml` is a part of my project):

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("MyXAMLFile.xaml");
String xamlContent= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
FrameworkElement rootObject = XamlReader.Load(xamlContent) as FrameworkElement;
```

Gives compilation error on StreamReader constructor.

> Argument 1 cannot convert string to System.IO.Stream

Indeed, `StreamReader(string)` doesn't appear in the list of constructors, though examples suggest that such a constructor should be.

Another attempt:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("MyXAMLPage.xml", FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
String xamlContent= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
FrameworkElement rootObject = XamlReader.Load(xamlContent) as FrameworkElement;
```

This time StreamReader initialisation is accepted, but the compilation error is with `FileStream`:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle'

even though `FilStream(string, FileAccess)` is listed as a valid constructor!

Answer (score 0):

just for note: you problem has no relationship at all with the Visual Studio version you are using.

you can try this.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("MyXAMLFile.xaml");
FrameworkElement rootObject = XamlReader.Load(streamReader) as FrameworkElement;
```

there is not overload for the "Load" method that take a string as parameter
see the MSDN documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx
so you must get compile time error.

you can use the Parse method instead like this

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("MyXAMLFile.xaml");
String xamlContent= streamReader.ReadToEnd();
object rootObject = XamlReader.Parse(xamlContent);
// here parse the rootObject to the appropriate type.
```

here is the documentation of the Parse method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663033(v=vs.110).aspx

try this for the constrcutor of the StreamReader

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path:"MyXAMLFile.xaml");
```

Comment: That may be another problem, but it still doesn't explain why I get compilation error with StreamReader constructor. Note that XamlReader.Load does NOT provide compilation error!

Comment: @cyanide I updated my answer to include possible solve for the StreamReader Constructor

Comment: @cyanide why "That my be another problem" can you explain this for me please. where is Exactly the problem with the answer

Comment: I tried: the error message is "The best overload for StreamReader doesn't have a parameter named path"

Comment: @cyanide can you please make sure that which "StreamReader" are you using, what is the included namespace, for the file, and try to specify the Full Qualified name to create the StreamReader

Comment: @cyanide try something like this                             System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path: "MyXAMLFile.xaml");

Comment: @cyanide if the previous did not work, try to make check on your assemblies

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it with Windows 8 and Windows 10.

1. Rename your xaml file to xml (otherwise it will be excluded from the project as redundant).
2. The code is the following:

   ```
   string xamlPath = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "MyXAMLFile.xml");
   XDocument xamlContent = XDocument.Load(xamlPath);
   FrameworkElement rootObject = XamlReader.Load(xamlContent.ToString()) as FrameworkElement;
   ```

Works just great!